# Build 2010 Project in TFS 2017

Tags: tfs, build, frameworks, tfsbuild

I have a 2010 project that needs built through TFS 2017. I am using the visual studio build task to do this.

The only options I am given to use are VS 2012 - 2017. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Build task has automatically set the `/p:VisualStudioVersion` property for us. And the versions only support VS 2012 - 2017.

The workaround is to use [MSBuild task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/build/msbuild?view=vsts) to specify MSBuild 4.0 version or specify the MSBuild location.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must upgrade your project to use the minimum supported visual studio version on the build task.